# How to use $_GET with mod_rewrite and AltoRouter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

I am having issues getting $_GET variables with mod_rewrite enabled. I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

and I am using "[AltoRouter](http://altorouter.com/)" for routing.

So an example of a Route that I might have is `/login?redirect=localhost%2Fnetwork%2Fdashboard` which would be rewritten as `/login`.

What I am trying to do is get `$_GET['redirect']` and I cannot seem to do this. Can anyone help? Apologies in advance for a bit of a code dump.

Comment: Its the last page that redirected to login. I want redirect it to same page after login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function helped me:

```
public static function _GET(){
    $__GET = array();
    $ru = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $_get_str = explode('?', $ru);
    if( !isset($_get_str[1]) ) return $__GET;
    $params = explode('&', $_get_str[1]);
    foreach ($params as $p) {
        $parts = explode('=', $p);
        $__GET[$parts[0]] = isset($parts[1])? $parts[1] : '';
    }
    return $__GET;
}
```

and:

```
$__GET = App::_GET();
$url = urldecode( $__GET['redirect'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't continue to use $_GET with AltoRouter.
Look [here](http://altorouter.com/usage/matching-requests.html) and [here](http://altorouter.com/usage/processing-requests.html)

Your problem may be that you are not [generating URLs](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter/blob/master/AltoRouter.php#L100) through AltoRouter.

Alto Router calls this "reverse routing" - look at the source:

```
/**
 * Reversed routing
 *
 * Generate the URL for a named route. Replace regexes with supplied parameters
 *
 * @param string $routeName The name of the route.
 * @param array @params Associative array of parameters to replace placeholders with.
 * @return string The URL of the route with named parameters in place.
 */
public function generate($routeName, array $params = array()) {
```

The way to get params in the URL:

```
$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->map( 'GET', '/', function() { .. }, 'home' );

// assuming current request url = '/'
$match = $router->match();

/*
array(3) { 
    ["target"]  => object(Closure)#2 (0) { } 
    ["params"]  => array(0) { } 
    ["name"]    => 'home' 
}
*/
```

Another example

```
$router = new AltoRouter();

// map homepage
$router->map( 'GET', '/', function() {
    require __DIR__ . '/views/home.php';
});

// map user details page
$router->map( 'GET', '/user/[i:id]/', function( $id ) {
    require __DIR__ . '/views/user-details.php';
});

// match current request url
$match = $router->match();

// call closure or throw 404 status
if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] ); 
} else {
    // no route was matched
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

Comment: I know it, but I like to get `$_GET['redirect']` from url.

Comment: your rewrite rule will not rewrite your long url to /login.  your rewrite rule sends all URLs that don't match to a file to index.php.  If you don't have a login file and you access `/login?redirect=localhost%2Fnetwork%2Fdashboard` you should be getting values in $_GET.  Posting your entire .htaccess file might be a good next step.

Comment: No I have a login page and `/login` route work well. I just want to get parameters after `/login` as $_GET. (Fo example get `redirect` parameter from `/login?redirect=path/to`).

Answer (score 0):

Old question but you can get the GET variables the same way before with $_GET, but you have to still match the route. I.e., if the route isn't matched your script doesn't proceed.

The route in altorouter for:

```
/login?redirect=localhost%2Fnetwork%2Fdashboard
```

Would be (you can use just GET or POST if you like) :

```
$router->map('GET|POST','/login/*', 'controllerforthisroute', "login");
```

After you can do `<?php echo $_GET['redirect'] ?>` and get:

```
localhost/network/dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but it seems it's not so easy to deal with Altorouter & query string parameters.

As explained [here](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter/issues/43) by the author, it's not suitable to output the query string parameters in Altorouter's `$match['parameters']` to respect REST principles.

Query string parameters have to be threated as external data, not part of Altorouter data.

---

**Here's a simple solution to retrieve the URL query string & register parameters in PHP global `$_GET`:**

```
// Register URL query string parameters in $_GET since Altorouter ROUTE doesn't deal with these.
$parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (isset($parts['query'])) {
    parse_str($parts['query'], $_GET);
}

// now we can use $_GET
// echo $_GET['something'];
```